# UIView position jumps a few pixels upwards while launching application in portraing mode

Tags: uiview, portrait

I have created simple windows based application. In my app delegate I have added a parentviewcontroller.view. In that parentview controller I am adding an image. Its position is given below.

In landscape: CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 54)
In portrait : CGRectMake(0, 0, 768, 54)

If I launch the app either in simulator/ipad, in landscape mode it shows perfectly. But when I launch the app in portrait mode, the top 20px of the UI and/or image is not being shown. But once I start changing the orientation it shows the image in correct position(in both landscape and portrait modes).

Please clarify me if I am doing anything wrong.

Thanks and Regards,
durai